# How to fix UserWarning and DeprecationWarning in Python

Tags: python, word2vec

I'm running some code that trains, saves and loads a Word2Vec model (it's part of a library I've downloaded, made by a user on github, as part of a published paper). Upon running it, two parts of the code seem to be problematic, although the code does actually run to the end.

The first error arises from a `method` called `train_word2vec()` (which is called as part of the main method of the program).

The second error arises from a line later in the main `method`.

## Problematic line 1 - within a method train_word2vec():

```
if exists(model_name):

embedding_model = word2vec.Word2Vec.load(model_name) #This line causes a UserWarning.
```

## Problematic line 2 - Later in the program, in the main method:

```
x_train, x_val, x_test, vocabulary, vocabulary_inv, sentences = load_data() #This line seems to run fine.

embedding_weights = train_word2vec(sentences, vocabulary_inv) #This line causes two DeprecationWarnings.
```

## The DeprecationWarnings are specifically created by the following line in train_word2Vec:

```
embedding_weights = [np.array([embedding_model[w] if w in embedding_model else np.random.uniform(-0.25,0.25,embedding_model.vector_size) for w in vocabulary_inv])]
```

Upon executing the code, the first problematic line causes a UserWarning:

" C:\Users\User1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\smart_open\smart_open_lib.py398: UserWarning: This function is deprecated, use smart_open.open instead. See the migration notes for details: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/blob/master/README.rst#migrating-to-the-new-open-function "

The second problematic line causes two DeprecationWarnings:

"
load_w2v.py:91: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated '**contains**' (Method will be removed in 4.0.0, use self.wv.**contains**() instead).
       embedding_weights = [np.array([embedding_model[w] if w in embedding_model else np.random.uniform(-0.25,0.25,embedding_model.vector_size) for w in vocabulary_inv])]"
"load_w2v.py:91: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated '**getitem**' (Method will be removed in 4.0.0, use self.wv.**getitem**() instead).
       embedding_weights = [np.array([embedding_model[w] if w in embedding_model else np.random.uniform(-0.25,0.25,embedding_model.vector_size) for w in vocabulary_inv])]
"

I've looked at the RaRe technologies README. What seems confusing is that nowhere in my code do I use the 'smart_open' function, so I don't understand why the first warning has been raised. smart_open isn't even in the imports at the start of the Python file.

Regarding the DeprecationWarnings, I use neither a 'contains' method nor a 'getitem' method in my code, so not sure where these warnings are coming from either.

As far as I can tell, the code seems to run properly, and the final file seems to have been created successfully. However, as I am recreating some code that somebody else has written, I am not certain that the file has been created properly.

Do `DeprecationWarnings` and `UserWarnings` actually indicate that the program has not executed successfully? Or are they there just as 'warnings'? I.e. is it possible for the code to run fine and 'warnings' still be thrown?

If anyone can see how I could alter the code to avoid these errors, that'd be appreciated. I'm new to Python so please point out any errors. Thanks.

Comment: If you haven't already, have a read of https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html. This doc gives you info about warnings in general, User and Deprecation warnings, and how to suppress their reporting. In general, your program should still be working just fine, in spite of the warnings.

Comment: Thanks Tom, that's useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can often ignore various 'warnings'. If they halted operation, or corrupted results, they'd appear as more serious errors or exceptions-that-must-be-handled for execution to proceed.

Specifically here, both warnings are actually about 'deprecation' of some method. That typically means a method's use is discouraged in favor of some newer, more-recommended approach – but still works for now (and possibly for quite a while longer).

With an abundance of caution, you could try to preemptively ensure all your code (and libraries) are using the most-recommended approaches – but it's not usually urgent or even necessary if things are otherwise working.

The notice about `smart_open` is essentially an issue for `gensim` to fix in a forthcoming release. The `smart_open` package changed it's preferred way of doing something, `gensim` is still using the older (still-working but 'deprecated') approach. You're not calling `smart_open` directly so it's not really your concern.

The notices about `contains` and `getitem` might be more under your control – they appear to be triggered by lines in a file `load_w2v.py` – which is not in `gensim`, and whose code you've not shown. In particular, `gensim` now encourages word-vector accesses to go through a `Word2Vec` model's `.wv` property, rather than through the top-level model (where these warnings will be generated). (Still, though, the old method works, and will until `gensim` decides to make a breaking change.)

If the warning display really bugs you, and you don't want to deep-dive into your code to avoid triggering them, then you can also simply suppress their display, as the comment & link from @tom-dalton describes.